# Different contact db on one iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts

I've seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276629/missing-icloud-contacts-on-one-device). I have the same problem, except that the incorrect contact list is on an iPhone. My iPad, and MBP are in sync.

How can I resend the iPhone so as 1. Not lose the correct contact list, and 2. Get the correct list onto my iPhone?

I've tried "turning it off and on again", thank you @Roy.
I've signed out and back in to iCloud on my iPhone.
I've turned off contacts on the phone, deleted the local set, and reconnected to iCloud, and turned on Contacts again.

I have over 500 contacts in iCloud, but only 50 on the device.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: anyone? please...

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps others:

1. Find a correct set of contacts on a Mac. I don't know Windows, this may work the same way.
2. Export them as a abbu file to save them. Contacts > File > Export > Contacts Archive.
3. If you don't have a good set of contacts, I suggest you log into iCloud.com. Go to Settings. At the bottom of the page, select "Restore Contacts". Cross fingers.
4. If you have a decent set of contacts on a Mac > Open Contacts.app. Highlight all contacts. Drag them to the iCloud tab.

[image]

5. Wait a bit until the list is uploaded to iCloud. Check this on iCloud.com > Contacts.
6. Your other devices should now sync properly.