# Exchange contact hidden in Address Book

Tags: mac, ms-office, contacts, exchange, contacts.app

I just added my Office 365 account via Exchange on my new MacBook Pro. After adding the account. I went into the Address Book app and saw that the global address list is empty. If I search for a person which I know is in that list it finds him or her, but the list still remains empty.

What can I do to make the list visible? If I access my Office account via the web I see the full list.

I have already tried the following:

- [Missing iCloud contacts on one device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276629/missing-icloud-contacts-on-one-device)
- Removing and adding my account

Comment: How long did you wait before checking for the GAL?  I don't believe it's an instant sync when connected so you might want to wait a few hours and check again.

Comment: @fsb: I have tried to wait for two days without luck.

Comment: Well that's not good :-/  Usually, just waiting helps me with other Exchange problems.  Hopefully, someone here can help with an answer.